# Automating POS application to do same action in different instances

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, web-application, qa-process

I have a POS application that works in different client bases. I need to test if I generate a bill at the same time from two different locations, will it gets interchanged or any such anomalies. Is it possible to automate this scenario ? Although the POS counters are at geographically at different locations, application is hosted in a single cloud server.

Comment: This is better to address on unit test level. Not sure if there is a reliable way to synchronize two client events on integration test level.

Comment: I agree with @AlexeyR., while it is possible to synchronize two clients to a reasonable degree you are looking into very precise synchronization here which is hard to achieve